# Variable argument list in C is not working

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I have tried to run the following code in C that uses stdarg.h but I can't get it to work for some reason. I have no experience using the variable argument lists so someone please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int add_stuff_together(int numb_count, ...);

int main()
{
    int x = add_stuff_together(2, 1, 1);

    printf("%i", x);

    return 0;
}

int add_stuff_together(int numb_count, ...)
{
    int sum, repeat_times;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numb_count);

    for (repeat_times = 0; repeat_times < numb_count; repeat_times++)
    {
        sum = sum +  va_arg(args, int);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The output I get is:
172998379

Can someone please explain why I get this answer?

Comment: Your compiler does not give any warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sum` variable is not initialized so its value can default to anything.

Also note that you dont use the `va_end()` macro, and you should do.

Comment: @JustinChadwell Because it may be needed to do some cleanup. From the man page: `Each invocation of va_start() must be matched by a corresponding  invocation of va_end() in the same function.`

Answer (score 4):

Because you don't initialize `sum` in `add_stuff_together()`, so its initial value is unspecified. You should initialize it to zero: `int sum = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You should initialise `sum` to zero before you start adding the numbers to it:

```
int sum = 0, repeat_times;
```

Otherwise, the starting value is arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int add_stuff_together(int numb_count, ...)
{
    int sum = 0;           //initializing sum to 0.
    int repeat_times;
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, numb_count);

    for (repeat_times = 0; repeat_times < numb_count; repeat_times++)
    {
        sum = sum +  va_arg(args, int);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Using `sum` without initializing will result in weird output and that's why you are getting the output `172998379`. This is because it will take garbage value from memory (previous value stored at that location).